# Displaying Last 10 Minutes of AWS IoT Core Data on Web Dashboard using AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Which AWS services can we use to transfer data from AWS IoT Core to our own web dashboard and display the last 10 minutes of data on the dashboard? In other words, how can we display the latest 10 minutes of data received from IoT Core on our web dashboard? The key point here is to send the data received from IoT Core in the last 10 minutes to the web dashboard. What would be the most efficient architecture to achieve this?

Help me please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t44qr.png)

I created https endpoint rule with aws iot rules. I send the data to the web dashboard with https endpoint but I want to send the last 10 minutes of data.

Comment: You can push the data from AWS IoT Core to AWS TimeStream, which is a time series database. AWS IoT Core is just an MQTT broker, it will not store data over time. From AWS TimeStream, you can pull data maybe using Grafana (there is a plugin for timestream). If you don't want to use TimeStream, you can always use another DB.

Comment: @brushtakopo How to pull data from Grafana? Is there API support? Can I do it using AWS Lambda?

Comment: Grafana is your dashboard. There is a grafana plugin for Timestream: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-timestream-datasource/

Comment: if you don't want to use grafana, then you can pull data from timestream using API gateway

Comment: It would be better to do it with API gateway, but can you suggest resources (videos etc.) for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below mentioned implementation guide which discusses architectural considerations and configuration steps for deploying Real-Time IoT Device Monitoring with Kinesis Data Analytics on the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Cloud. It includes links to an AWS CloudFormation template that launches, configures, and runs the AWS services required to deploy this solution using AWS best practices for security and availability.

[Real-Time IoT Device Monitoring with Kinesis Data Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/real-time-iot-device-monitoring-with-kinesis/architecture.html)

You can also refer to the below-mentioned blog for different IoT reporting and visualization solutions at AWS.

[7 patterns for IoT data ingestion and visualization- How to decide what works best for your use case](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/7-patterns-for-iot-data-ingestion-and-visualization-how-to-decide-what-works-best-for-your-use-case/)

Further, Kindly refer the below mentioned AWS solution where it will ingests real-time device data from IoT devices to assess the state of each IoT device and send you notifications if there are data transmission issues or out of range data.

[Remote Monitoring of IoT Devices](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/remote-monitoring-of-iot-devices/)